# Binding vs Explicit Assignment of a Variable

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, binding

I am thinking about the following issue.

If I have for example a textbox/slider/combobox which value is bound to something like

```
<TextBox Name=textBox Text="{Binding Text}"/>
```

and then do

```
textBox.Text = "something"
```

Is it going to "override" the binding or is binding "stronger" then explicit assignment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the binding will be overwritten.

Answer (score 2):

No it won't update your binding. Binding gets updated only when it comes from View, if you set it from your code behind, it will override the text but will break the binding. You can try this sample -

- Place a textbox on your view and bind it's text property to some
  property in your viewmodel say value for this property is "Test"
- Now place two button's on your view.
- On first button click simply set the text of your textbox to
  something say "Button1".
- You will notice that textbox text will now be "Button1" but still the value of your CLR property will be "Test".
- Now on second button click, try to set your Viewmodel property to say
  "Button2". PropertyChanged will be fired but you won't notice any
  change in your textbox text.

If you want to update the binding, you have to set the Dependency property from your code behind like this-

```
textBox.SetCurrentValue(TextBox.TextProperty, "Button2");
```

where textBox is your name of the TextBox.

Comment: Oh!! Haven't worked much on Silverlight. So, must be some other way to set DP's in silverlight?

Comment: You just get the standard `SetValue` which is tantamount to assigning to the POCO property anyway so unless the binding is TwoWay you can't muck about with the target property without breaking the binding in Silverlight.

Comment: Thanks Rohit for detailed explanation !! Was helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just simply put the value you will like to be in the textbox in the "Text" memeber of the bound object. Otherwise the binding will be overwritten, as devdigital mentioned above.